# when i try to run my angular project i get these error

Tags: angular, angular-material

Error: node_modules/@angular/material/radio/radio.d.ts:184:9 - error TS2611: 'disabled' is defined as a property in class 'CanDisableRipple & HasTabIndex & MatRadioButtonBase', but is overridden here in '_MatRadioButtonBase' as an accessor.

184     get disabled(): boolean;
~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@angular/material/table/cell.d.ts:42:5 - error TS2610: 'name' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkColumnDef', but is overridden here in 'MatColumnDef' as an instance property.

42     name: string;
~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `tsconfig` file by setting `"useDefineForClassFields": true`.

Comment: i'll try that bt it wil not run proper